# Is there any GUI tool to configure /etc/fstab?

Tags: linux, debian, gui, fstab

I have little experiences in configuring the 'fstab'. I'm looking for any GUI tool that helps me with this. If possible based on gtk and should be available in Debian.

Comment: What distro? There are usually tools bundled with your distribution...

Comment: @haimg  
Debian. I've edited it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about [pysdm](http://pysdm.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: The old kfstab was a good tool for this, but it's sadly bitrotten by now. There're [fwfstab](http://www.diffingo.com/oss/fwfstab) and [gfstab](http://sørenj.dk/?page_id=129) as well, but they don't seem maintained. In the future I expect the excellent palimpsest will evolve the ability to actually edit fstab, then all will be well.

Comment: It seems like this package has now been removed from Debian/Ubuntu as its out of date - doesn't support UUIDs for example.

Comment: @phogg a decade later.. I've been using gnome-disks for a long time to mount by clicking the play button, which mounts in Ubuntu to the standard /media/username/.. However, I want to use this as a utility for my fstab, but although it allows me to use the label under 'identify as' I dont see a way to automount under /media instead of /mnt. Is there? It must be able to if the play button works. Perhaps there is a env var that points there? I'd like to keep the dirs standard. I can type it out, but it would be great to have that option.

Answer (score 31):

Now Gnome comes with a very powerful tool for this, Disks. (Formerly known as Palimpsest; it looks like phogg's prediction was accurate).

[image: A screenshot of disks editing a mount]

Comment: The command is `sudo gnome-disks`

Comment: @knb, you shouldn't use sudo.  Only udisks2 runs as root.

Comment: It's still just a string of obfuscated parameters, though.  `nosuid,nodev,nofail,compress=lzo...` it needs checkboxes and dropdowns and explanations for what each of these options does.

Comment: fstab is not only about disks but also about temp filesystem, bind, NFS etc.

Answer (score 5):

I use gnome-disk-utility which provides the GUI tool 'Disks'

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility
```

I'm using this in Linux Mint 17.3 (Ubuntu/Debian based) with cinnamon.

You also mention in a comment that you are not a gnome user, but you have not specified what you are using?

see also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Disks

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Clicking the gear icon for a particular partition in disks provides a menu option called 'Edit Mount Options'. Here in, set the Automatic Mount Options to 'OFF'. Thereafter proceed to define your custom mount point (for that you may wish to create your directory e.g. sudo mkdir /mnt/windows)

The comments=gvfs-show is key (don't forget to the comment= else it won't work in Ubuntu 14.04)

Changing the filesystem type from auto to the correct type (ntfs, ext4, xfs etc.) is also recommended.